# Really stuck on Android/Java. Touch Event on a Sprite button to perform specific action

Tags: java, android, 2d

I have been really stuck on this for the past day or so and I could really use somebody's input as to where I'm going wrong

So I have a 'Play Game' image, I'm loading it into my game as follows:

```
playGame = new SimpleControl(250.0f, 225.0f, 140.0f, 30.0f, "PlayBtn", this);
```

The SimpleControl object looks like this:

```
public SimpleControl(float x, float y, float width, float height,
                     String bitmapName, GameScreen gameScreen) {
    super(x, y, width, height, gameScreen.getGame().getAssetManager()
            .getBitmap(bitmapName), gameScreen);

public boolean isActivated() {

    // Consider any touch events occurring in this update
    Input input = mGameScreen.getGame().getInput();

    // Check if any of the touch events were on this control
    BoundingBox bound = getBound();
    for (int idx = 0; idx < TouchHandler.MAX_TOUCHPOINTS; idx++) {
        if (input.existsTouch(idx)) {
            if (bound.contains(input.getTouchX(idx), input.getTouchY(idx))) {
                return true; }}}
return false; }
```

I have an update method in my Game class which goes like this:

```
Input input = mGame.getInput();
    List<TouchEvent> touchEvents = input.getTouchEvents();
    if (touchEvents.size() > 0) {
        TouchEvent touchevent = touchEvents.get(0);
        {
            if (playGame.isActivated()) {
                mGame.getScreenManager().removeScreen(this.getName());
                AboutScreen aboutScreen = new AboutScreen(mGame);
                mGame.getScreenManager().addScreen(aboutScreen);
            }
```

Unfortunately when I'm running this, the button does not pick up any touch event but there's a little section of the screen that does:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/6kyeh.png

```
BoundingBox.java:
public BoundingBox(float x, float y, float halfWidth, float halfHeight) {
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
    this.halfWidth = halfWidth;
    this.halfHeight = halfHeight;
}

public boolean contains(float x, float y) {
    return (this.x - this.halfWidth < x && this.x + this.halfWidth > x
            && this.y - this.halfHeight < y && this.y + this.halfHeight > y);
}
```

Thank you in advance :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `contains(float x, float y)` looks incorrect.

`this.x - this.halfwidth < x` means it checks for `x` at a location before the start of the bounding box.

For example your x should be - 
`(x>=this.x && x<=(this.x + 2*this.halfwidth))` 
And y should be 
`(y>=this.y && y<=(this.y + 2.this.halfHeight))`

(Assuming halfWidth and halfHeight are what they say)
(also, can't open the imgur link since its blocked for us)